# SQL query that generates InMemoryDatabase test failure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, xunit, in-memory-database

I've got an xUnit InMemoryDatabase failure.

```
var selectedPeople = _context.People
                .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id) && x.Valid &&
                         selectedFunctions.Any(function => 
                              x.Functions.Any(r => r.FunctionId == function.Id)));
```

The error thrown is the following one:

```
Failed: System.InvalidOperationException : Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'where {from Function function in __selectedFunctions_1 where {from DbPersonFunction f in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1 where ([f].FunctionId == [function].Id) where  ?= (Property([x], "Id") == Property([f], "PersonId")) =? select [f] => Any()} select [function] => Any()}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.
```

The query is already doing the right thing, but after the EF upgrade the unit test that's calling the method using the above query would fail. I believe that re-writing the query would solve the issue?

Comment: "the issue", which issue specifically? Do you get an exception? If so what are the details of the exception? Does it not do what you want it to do? If so what did you expect it to do and what did it do instead? Basically, we need more issues than just "there's an issue here".

Comment: Moved from EF Core 1 or 2.0 to 2.1`?  The query already had a bug - the query you posted can't be translated to SQL. EF Core 1 didn't implement a *lot* of functionality, so when it couldn't translate the query to SQL it loaded all data in memory and evaluated the query in memory. That's *very* bad. EF Core 2.1 started emitting warnings about this. EF Core 3 disabled the "functionality" completely

Comment: The solution is to fix the query. You didn't post the defintion of `selectedFunctions` but it looks like it's a list of objects instead of a list of IDs. This can't be translated into SQL. If you want to filter by the related functions based on the ID, store the selected IDs in a list and use `Contains` the same way you did for IDs. If the method-style query gets too complex you can use query syntax, eg `from p in _ctx.People from f in p.Functions where funcIds.Contains(f.Id) && ids.Contains(p.Id) && p.Valid select p;`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @PanagiotisKanavos. It was really clear and useful! I re-wrote the query as you suggested and it works now. And fully noted everything. Also, if I may ask, in EF Core 3 I observed that the same problem happens when we use for example something like this `_context.People.Where(p  => ids.Contains(p.Id)).GroupBy(b.FunctionsId)`. By adding `.ToList()` after the `.Where()` statement would fix the issue, but is there any other way to approach this?